# Shell command "where" duplicate output

Tags: macos, shell, unix, zsh

`ls -al /usr/local/bin/shopify` produces following output

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin  39 19 Jan 11:53 /usr/local/bin/shopify -> ../Cellar/shopify-cli/1.5.0/bin/shopify`

Why is the output of `where shopify` duplicate?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have /usr/local/bin twice in your PATH?

Comment: yep you were right

Comment: Tipp (since you are using zsh): If you put into your .zshrc or .zshenv a `typeset -aU path`, duplicates are automatically removed from the PATH.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I first placed it before the exports, then I moved it to the end and got it working. I've another question: There're some entries in my path which aren't set in .zshrc, eg. ruby, tex etc. How do I find out where they are set?

Comment: just found /etc/paths

Comment: @zinyosrim Since your problem got solved, can you close your question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as user1934428 commented, the path was listed twice in the `.zshrc`.
To avoid this in the future I put `typeset -aU path` after the last export statetement